# NGSwitchery onchange event

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on single-page web app using `angularjs`.

I'm using `NGSwitchery` directive for checkbox.

I want to handle an `on-change` event when user switching the `NGSwitchery` control.

I tried to attach `ng-model` and `ng-change`, but it's not working.

Is there any way?

Following is the code I tried.

`Template`

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="socialsharing_facebook" class="js-switch" ui-switch ng-model="user.enable_facebook" ng-checked="user.enable_facebook == 1" ng-change="updateUser()" />
```

`updateUser()` isn't called, when I change switch.

Comment: Do you have a plunkr or equivalent to demonstrate what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used NGSwitchery, but usually you can just [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) the model from your controller. The nice thing about that is that if the model changes by some other means, you will be notified of that too. Something like this:

```
$scope.$watch("user.enable_facebook", $scope.updateUser);
```